# Split a text into words, digits and punctuation marks

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I need to split a phrase into words, digits, punctuation marks, and spaces/tabs. I also would like to preserve the order of things.

```
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The 3 quick:\"brown fox, jump's\" over."];
```

This is the kind of list I need to yield:

```
['The', ' ', '3', ' ', 'quick, ':', '"', 'brown', ' ', 'fox', ',', ' ', 'jump's', ' ', '.']
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Where did you get the space between "quick" and ":"?

Comment: Should all-digit strings be preserved or split? In other words, does `The 333 quick` become `["The", " ", "333", " ", "quick"]`, or `["The", " ", "3", "3", "3", " ", "quick"]`?

Comment: Digits should be preserved. "333" would remain 333.

Comment: Where did you get the space between "quick" and ":"? Fixed, Thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this category I wrote using a `NSScanner` & `NSCharacterSet`:

```
@interface NSString(Splitting)

-(NSArray *) arrayBySeparatingComponentsInCharacterSet:(NSCharacterSet *) charSet;

@end

@implementation NSString(Splitting)

BOOL scanOneCharacterFromSetIntoString(NSScanner *self, NSCharacterSet * charSet, NSString **outStr);
BOOL scanOneCharacterFromSetIntoString(NSScanner *self, NSCharacterSet * charSet, NSString **outStr)
{
    // check for index out of bounds
    NSString *inStr = self.string;

    if (self.scanLocation >= inStr.length)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    unichar ch = [inStr characterAtIndex:self.scanLocation];

    if (![charSet characterIsMember:ch])
    {
        return NO;
    }

    self.scanLocation++;
    if (outStr)
    {
        *outStr = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&ch length:1];
    }

    return YES;
}

-(NSArray *) arrayBySeparatingComponentsInCharacterSet:(NSCharacterSet *)charSet
{
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:self];
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSString *temp = nil;
    while ([scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:charSet intoString:&temp] || scanOneCharacterFromSetIntoString(scanner, charSet, &temp)) {;
        [result addObject:temp];

        if ([scanner scanLocation] >= [self length])
        {
            break;
        }

        unichar temp2 = [self characterAtIndex:[scanner scanLocation]];

        if ([charSet characterIsMember:temp2])
        {
            [result addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", temp2]];
            // only update the scan location if the scan was sucessful
            [scanner setScanLocation:[scanner scanLocation] + 1];
        }
    }

    return result;
}

@end

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSString *str = @"The 3 quick:\"brown fox, jump's\" over.";
        NSArray *array = [str arrayBySeparatingComponentsInCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" :\",'."]];
        NSLog(@"%@", array);
    }
}
```

Should be what you need, just change the Character Set to what you need. Also note that this was compiled with ARC enabled, so it may or may not work properly with memory management in a reference counted environment.

Comment: Thank you! It worked marvellously. You saved me of loads of frustration, not to mention time.

Comment: Hey, no problem, just happy to help.

Comment: One problem:    NSString *str = @"hello world...";
More than one punctuation character at the end of sentence causes crash. Also any ideas how to handle ellipsis (three dots "...")?

Comment: Go ahead and try the newest version, it should work with 3+ tokens in a row now.

Comment: Thanks for this implementation. Edited to fix a bug. I was passing the inverse of the alphanum character set in. (E.g. all punctuation and whitespace.) Given the input text "this, that", the space character was not present at all in the output. Needed to add `[scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];`.